# Get key and value of a JavaScript array into variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript object array. When write `console.log(myarry)` it will show in the console in the below form.

```
Array[2]
0: Object
one: "one"

1: Object
two: "two"
length: 2
```

In this array my key and value are same and am trying to get the key or value to a variable and print it. When am trying the below code it showing:

> object object

```
for (var key in myarry) {
 alert("Key is " + key + ", value is" + myarry[key]);
}
```

Comment: Use `for-loop` instead of `for-in` to iterate array... Also read about `Object.keys` to get keys of `object`

Comment: can you show me your code before the `for` where do you assign the value to `myarray`.

Comment: Actually the array  coming from a third party api and i can see the array when i write console.log(myarry) in the above format. My aim is to get the key or value into a variable. I have tried with for loop too. But it also showing object object.

Comment: It's not "java script" or "java-script"; it's "JavaScript".

Comment: When an object is "printed" (i.e., converted to a string), it becomes `[object Object]`. If you want to print out some reasonable representation of the object, you can use `JSON.stringify`, or do the string conversion yourself however you want.

Comment: sorry I was in the work so I mistaken send the answer. Now I edited and it is ok.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

check this snippet

```js
var obj = [{
  "1": "one"
}, {
  "2": "two"
}]
obj.forEach(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log("key:" + key + "value:" + item[key]);
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

- Use **`for-loop`** instead of `for-in` to iterate array.
- Use [**`Object.keys`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get keys of `object`

```js
var arr = [{
  one: 'one'
}, {
  two: 'two'
}];

for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var keys = Object.keys(arr[i]);
  for (var j = 0, k = keys.length; j < k; j++) {
    console.log("Key:" + keys[j] + "  Value:" + arr[i][keys[j]]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two main options to get keys of an object using `Object.keys` these are: `forEach`; or a simple `for`.

#### 1. Use `forEach`

If you're using an environment that supports the `Array` features of ES5 (directly or using a shim), you can use the new `forEach`:

```js
var myarray = [{one: 'one'}, {two: 'two'}];

myarray.forEach(function(item) {
  var items = Object.keys(item);
  items.forEach(function(key) {
   console.log('this is a key-> ' + key + ' & this is its value-> ' + item[key]);
 });
});
```

`forEach` accepts an iterator function and, optionally, a value to use as `this` when calling that iterator function (not used above). The iterator function is called for each entry in the array, in order, skipping non-existent entries in sparse arrays. Although

`forEach` has the benefit that you don't have to declare indexing and value variables in the containing scope, as they're supplied as arguments to the iteration function, and so nicely scoped to just that iteration.

If you're worried about the runtime cost of making a function call for each array entry, don't be; [technical details](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18).

#### 2. Use a simple `for`

Sometimes the old ways are the best:

```js
var myarray = [{one: 'one'}, {two: 'two'}];

for (var i = 0, l = myarray.length; i < l; i++) {
  var items = myarray[i];
  var keys = Object.keys(items);
  for (var j = 0, k = keys.length; j < k; j++) {
    console.log('this is a key-> ' + keys[j] + ' & this is its value-> ' + items[keys[j]]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your construction, you can do

```js
const arr = [{ key1: 'val1' }, { key2: 'val2' }]

arr.forEach((a, i) =>
  console.log(i, [{ key: Object.keys(a) }, { val: Object.values(a) }])
)
```

and to answer your question

```js
arr.forEach((a, i) =>
  alert("Key is "+ Object.keys(a) + ", value is " +  Object.values(a))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> am trying to get the key or value to a variable and print it.

then you could

```js
var myarry = [{ one: 'one' }, { two: 'two' }];

for (var key in myarry) {
  var value = myarry[key];
  console.log(key, value)
}
```

Comment: I have tried. I can see the value in console. But when i print, it still showing object object. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way

```js
const a = [{ one: 'one' }, { two: 'two' }];

a.forEach(function(value,key) {
   console.log(value,key);
});
```

You can take key and value in a variable and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting way to do it.

```js
const arr = [{ one: 'one' }, { two: 'two' }];

Object.entries(arr).forEach(([_, obj]) => {
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  console.log(`Key is ${key}, value is ${obj[key]}.`);
});
```