# Javascript: for..in loop running more number of times than expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop

In the following code, the actual length of user.roles is 1. However, the loop runs two times.

When I output the value of i, it is shown as 'diff' for the second iteration.
Switching to the ordinary for loop resolved the situation.
However, I'd like to know what the issue is with the **for..in** loop.

```
 for (var i in user.roles) {
                if (user.roles[i].school.equals(schoolId)) {
                    for (var j in user.roles[i].permissions) {
                        for (var k in accessType) {
                            if (user.roles[i].permissions[j].feature == featureKey) {
                                if (user.roles[i].permissions[j][accessType[k]]) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Update: user is an object, and roles is an array of objects. The instance of roles that caused the issue is shown below:

```
{
  "_id": "582d3390d572d05c1f028f53",
  "displayName": "Test Teacher Attendance",
  "gender": "Male",
  "roles": [
    {
      "_id": "57a1b3ccc71009c62a48a684",
      "school": "57a1b3ccc71009c62a48a682",
      "role": "Teacher",
      "__v": 0,
      "designation": true,
      "permissions": [
        {
          "feature": "User",
          "_id": "57ac0b9171b8f0b82befdb7d",
          "review": false,
          "view": true,
          "delete": false,
          "edit": false,
          "create": false
        },
        {
          "feature": "Notice",
          "_id": "57ac0b9171b8f0b82befdb7c",
          "review": false,
          "view": true,
          "delete": false,
          "edit": false,
          "create": false
        },

      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: can you define user, roles, permission, accessType? those are objects, strings, integers.

Comment: Is `user.roles` an Array/Iterator? Maybe you should use `for .. of`

Comment: Why do you use `for in` ? try to use `forEach` . Its more convenient.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614054/javascript-nuances-of-myarray-foreach-vs-for-loop

Comment: @Teocci user.roles is an array of objects, and permissions is an array of objects inside user.roles. accessType is a string array.

Comment: @AllenGJ can you mark my question as the answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.roles` seems to be an array. And for array you should not use for in.

Simple example

```
var arr = [2];
arr.s = 3;

for (var i  in arr) {
console.log("here"); // paints twice
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), **The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.**

How to choose the type of iterator, here is a reference [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

**EDIT**

As per the updated question, the above can only come with a property as `diff` if somewhere in the code following is present

```
Array.prototype.diff = .....
```

Comment: Thanks. However, in this case, user.roles only seems to have one enumberable property, right?
ie, it only has one object in it.
When I console the value of **i**, for the second (unexpected) iteration, it holds the value '**diff**'.

Comment: If that is the case then there must be `Array.prototype.diff` in your code somewhere.

Comment: @AllenGJ - Did you checked? Additionally, you can delete it via `delete Array.prototype.diff;`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what are you looking for. 
I assume that your `accessTypes` is an array that contains the following items:

`var accessTypes = ["review", "view", "delete", "edit", "create"];`

**Edited** to improve the efficiency.

```js
var schoolId = "57a1b3ccc71009c62a48a682";
var featureKey = "Notice";
var accessTypes = ["review", "view", "delete", "edit", "create"];

var user = {
  "_id": "582d3390d572d05c1f028f53",
  "displayName": "Test Teacher Attendance",
  "gender": "Male",
  "roles": [{
    "_id": "57a1b3ccc71009c62a48a684",
    "school": "57a1b3ccc71009c62a48a682",
    "role": "Teacher",
    "__v": 0,
    "designation": true,
    "permissions": [{
      "feature": "User",
      "_id": "57ac0b9171b8f0b82befdb7d",
      "review": false,
      "view": true,
      "delete": false,
      "edit": false,
      "create": false
    }, {
      "feature": "Notice",
      "_id": "57ac0b9171b8f0b82befdb7c",
      "review": false,
      "view": true,
      "delete": false,
      "edit": false,
      "create": false
    }]
  }]
};

user.roles.forEach(function(roleItem) {
  // console.log('This is a role: ' + roleItem.school);
  if (roleItem.school == schoolId) {
    roleItem.permissions.forEach(function(permissionItem) {
      // console.log('This is a permission: ' + permissionItem.feature);
      // console.log('This is a accessType: ' + accessType);
      if (permissionItem.feature == featureKey) {
        accessTypes.forEach(function(accessType) {
          if (permissionItem[accessType]) {
            console.log('accessType: ' + accessType + ' -> true');
            return true;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

`forEach` accepts an iterator function. The iterator function is called for each entry in the array, in order, skipping non-existent entries in sparse arrays.

`forEach`, also, has the benefit that you don't have to declare indexing and value variables in the containing scope, as they're supplied as arguments to the iteration function, and so nicely scoped to just that iteration.

If you're worried about the runtime cost of making a function call for each array entry, don't be; more [technical details](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18).

If you still have the impression that `forEach` is fundamentally slower you can use a simple `for` loop as I explain in another of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647538/#40647652).

Hope that this helps you.

Comment: What about the performance? I was under the impression that forEach is fundamentally slower.

Comment: @AllenGJ If you still have the impression that `forEach` is fundamentally slower you can use a simple `for` loop as I explain in another [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647538/#40647652).